# What is the CMYK color profile used by pantone.com

Tags: color, color-management, colorspace

Pantone spot colors are specified in the RGB and CMYK color models on the https://pantone.com website. For example, the [Pantone 122 spot color as it appears when printed on coated paper](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/122-C) is specified as RGB 254, 209, 65 and as CMYK 0, 9, 80, 0.

Since the RGB color is also specified as HEX/HTML #FED141, I assume that the color is specified in the sRGB color space, see [CSS Color Module Level 3, Section 4.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#rgb-color):

> All RGB colors are specified in the sRGB color space (see [[SRGB]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#ref-SRGB)). […]

However, what would be the CMYK color space / color profile? My wild guess would be the U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2, which is the default CMYK color space in Photoshop, but there are many other color profiles, which produce different colors for the same CMYK quadruplet.

Additionally, why are there separate CMYK quadruplets for the [Pantone 122 spot color as it appears when printed on coated paper](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/122-C) and [when printed on coated paper](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/122-U). I would expect a single CMYK quadruplet, which would result appear differently based on the paper used, just like there is just a single Pantone 122 spot color.